# Can't choose master branch/docs folder when trying to change the source of my github page

Tags: git, macos, github

thanks for taking your time to help me :)

I am trying to publish my HTML website however it does not allow me to use the master branch/ docs folder. Now I'm using my username in my link like this: `https://djcinoj.github.io/token_sale/.` I know it says that you cant use your username if you want to use the docs folder however a video that I have linked at the bottom from May 21, 2018, he can. I have been following this set of tutorial for the last 2 months and been doing exactly the same as him. Why can't I use my username and he can?

I expect to be able to use the docs folder which I have in my repository however its grayed out and I can't click it when I try to change my source. Maybe check my repository I have also added a link at the bottom. It could be that there is no way to do it. But what I'm trying to achieve is to lanuch the website maybe there is another way you can do it that the video does not show. By launching the website I mean that I can send the link to anyone and that person can use it.

Thanks so much for your help

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-vsaoyuoww&index=16&list=PLS5SEs8ZftgWFuKg2wbm_0GLV0Tiy1R-n

Repository: https://github.com/DJCinoJ/token_sale

[Picture of how my folder looks like in Atom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvMBl.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/#publishing-your-github-pages-site-from-a-docs-folder-on-your-master-branch

> have a /docs folder **in the root** of the repository

(Emphasized by me — phd).

You don't have `/docs` in the root, you have it in `/token_sale/` subdirectory.

Comment: How can delete my token sale directory but still have all my other files that are in that folder?

Comment: Just move them: `git mv token_sale/* . && git rm token_sale && git commit`.

Comment: Do i put that whole line of code in terminal or what do I do? sorry but this is my first time doing this

Comment: Yep, these are commands for `git-bash` or other terminal. The current directory must be the root of the repo.

Comment: If I put `git mv token_sale/* . && git rm token_sale && git commit` in terminal when I'm in my token_sale directory the output I get is `fatal: bad source, source=token_sale/token_sale/*, destination=token_sale/*`

Comment: I have looked at all the links but none of them seem to help me. If you look at my Repository I have all my files in that one token_sale folder right? how do I remove that folder but still have all the files inside it and not accidentally deleting them?

Comment: You have to move all files up 1 level and then remote the empty `token_sales`. Not neccessary with `git` — you can do with any file manager and then run `git add -A .`

Comment: Could you please give me step by step instructions on what I have to do? I don't know how to move all files up 1 level or how to then remote the empty token_sales. Thanks so much I really appreciate your help

Comment: I don't think this is my problem. I have included an image in the post itself to show you my folder when I look at it on my computer. Meaning if I move up all the folders one level it might be impossible because then the token_sale folder would not exist anymore. Have a look at the image I have left on the post maybe that helps. Also since I noticed that you sent these links for windows it might be important that I say I'm using a mac. Thank You

Comment: I don't need to look at your desktop. The question is about Github Pages — so I only looked at the repository. In the repository there is no `/docs/` folder — instead, there is `/token_sale/docs/`, and that's why Github Pages don't show docs.

Comment: Alright I got it to work thank you so much for your patience and help I really really really appreciate it you have no idea this was the last step to completing my ICO website :)