# Github Pages source options dropdown not appearing

Tags: angular, github, github-pages

I have a static Angular site created for my github user site.

I have been following the [github guide](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site) to choosing the source folder and I'm trying to use the /docs folder as a publishing source but there is no dropdown with the option to choose the /docs folder.
[image: Missing dropdown]

And the guide shows that there should be these options (from the github guide):

[image: Expected dropdown]

I have a master branch with a docs folder:

[image: Master branch and docs folder]

I have looked into the differences between user pages and project pages, and this is definetly a **user** page.

What am I missing? Why don't I have the option?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54036571/5987698) could be relevant.

Comment: @GoodDeeds As I stated in the question
 > "I have a master branch with a **docs** folder"
I already have a /docs folder **in the root**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `master` branch is the only possible publishing source for a user site.

As per [this help page](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#publishing-sources-for-github-pages-sites) (emphasis mine):

> The default publishing source for user and organization sites is the `master` branch. If the repository for your user or organization site has a `master` branch, your site will publish automatically from that branch. **You cannot choose a different publishing source for user or organization sites.**

The option to select the `docs/` folder is only for project sites.